# Adding Submenu Item Only on Devices other than Mac: Electron JS

Tags: javascript, menu, electron, menuitem

I would like to add a quit submenu item under the File menu item in my Electron JS app, but ***only on Windows and Linux***. On Mac, I already have set up a Quit submenu item under the app name menu item. Currently, this is my code:

```
function createMenu(){
    const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin';
    const menu = [
        
        {
            label: "File",
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Add expense',
                },
                !isMac && { 
                    label: 'Quit',
                    click(){
                        app.quit()
                    },
                    accelerator: 'Ctrl+Q'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Menu2",
            submenu: [{label: 'Ok'}]
        }
    ];


    // Mac First Item in Template refers to app name (won't be able to override unless you package application)
    isMac && menu.unshift({
        label: app.name,
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'About',
                click(){
                    open('https://www.google.com') // Using the open package
                }
            }, 
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                click(){
                    app.quit()
                },
                accelerator: 'Cmd+Q'
            }
        ]
    })


    return menu;
    
}
```

When I run this, however, I get an error saying

```
TypeError: Invalid template for MenuItem: must have at least one of label, role or type
```

How should I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because of the way you're trying to conditionally insert an object into the list literal.

```js
// The not macOS case:
> [ {"foo": 15}, true && {"bar": 123} ]
[ { foo: 15 }, { bar: 123 } ]

// The macOS case:
> [ {"foo": 15}, false && {"bar": 123} ]
[ { foo: 15 }, false ]
```

In the latter case, you end up inserting a `false` element into the array, which is why you get the error.

If you want to use such a shorthand, you can use:

```js
> [ {"foo": 15}, ...(true?[{"bar": 123}]:[]) ]
[ { foo: 15 }, { bar: 123 } ]

> [ {"foo": 15}, ...(false?[{"bar": 123}]:[]) ]
[ { foo: 15 } ]
```

In your use case, this would get you:

```js
const menu = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Add expense',
            },
            ...(!isMac)?[{ 
                label: 'Quit',
                click(){
                    app.quit()
                },
                accelerator: 'Ctrl+Q'
            }]:[]
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "Menu2",
        submenu: [{label: 'Ok'}]
    }
];
```

Alternatively, you can simply adjust the menu template:

```js
const menu = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Add expense',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "Menu2",
        submenu: [{label: 'Ok'}]
    }
];

if (!isMac) {
    menu[0]["submenu"].push({ 
        label: 'Quit',
        click(){
            app.quit()
        },
        accelerator: 'Ctrl+Q'
    })
}
```

Which one to use is up to you; in the second case you may need to update the menu addressing if the structure changes. You should also weigh readability.